# Convert a unixtime stamp for php

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need to know how to convert a unix time stamp into how much time left from now to that timestamp. If the time left is 1 day it has to show 1 day or if it is  15 min , shows %dMin so on for week, hours, years, months.

Currently I use

```
$realtime = strftime("%B %d %Y %r",1295058844);
```

Comment: please use the search function before asking questions. How to get time differences has been answered many times before. We expect you to do research.

Answer (score 1):

First get a difference between the current timestamp (returned by time()):

```
$timestamp = 1295058844;

$diff = time() - $timestamp;
```

And then write a function that will format the result into days/hours/minutes etc. For example, you can get the number of days by divinding $diff by the number of seconds that make 1 day:

```
$days = floor($diff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours. Since that number never change, you can just write:

```
$days = floor($diff / 86400);
```

Get the remaining seconds and compute number of hours, minutes etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily by using PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) classes:-

```
$futureDate = new DateTime('3rd April 2014');
```

Or

```
$futureDate = new DateTime();
$futureDate->setTimestamp(1295058844);
```

You get the idea.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $futureDate->diff($now);
```

This will give you a [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) object:-

```
var_dump($diff);

object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 1
  public 'm' => int 3
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 9
  public 'i' => int 8
  public 's' => int 58
  public 'invert' => int 1
  public 'days' => int 455
```

Then you can do something like this:-

```
echo "Time left = {$diff->y} years, {$diff->m} months, {$diff->d} days, {$diff->h} hours, {$diff->i} minutes, {$diff->s} seconds";
```

Gives:-

> Time left = 1 years, 3 months, 0 days, 9 hours, 8 minutes, 58 seconds